# java spring - failing to test rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit

I have a 3-tier service an a spring application server.
the service essentially gets some parameters (through a REST API) calls
a corresponding service class that calls the corresponding repository class that performs a select SQL statement from the DB (using JDBC).

when I run the Tomcat Server and test the API through a rest client it works fine.

and now for my issue - I'm trying to test the API with the bellow code
and instead of ok status I get 404

```
public class AdServersReportsResourceIntegrationTest extends AbstractControllerIntegrationTest
{

private final int responseStatusOK = 200;


@Test
public void getReport() throws Exception 
{


    Response response = target("adserver").queryParam("fromDate","2015-11-28").queryParam("toDate", "2015-11-30").queryParam("adServer", 1).queryParam("campaign", "569588").queryParam("groupBy", "site").request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(Response.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(responseStatusOK, response.getStatus());            
}
```

the Resource class looks like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Path("/adserver")
public class AdServersReportsResource extends Resource{
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdServersReportsResource.class);

@Autowired
private AdServersReportsService adServersReportsService;

@GET    
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getCampaignCapturedEventsReport(
        @QueryParam("fromDate") String strdayStart,
        @QueryParam("toDate") String strdayEnd,
        @QueryParam("adServer") Integer adServerID, 
        @QueryParam("campaign") String campaignID, 
        @QueryParam("groupBy") String groupBy){

    //input parameter validation

    String response = adServersReportsService.getAdServerComparison(strdayStart,strdayEnd,adServerID,campaignID,groupBy).toString();
    return createObjectSuccessResponse(response);

    }
}
```

after some trial and error I found out that if I replace the JDBC code with a stub the test works.
the weird thing is that I trying changing the JDBC code so that it executes SQL 
with hard-coded parameters which I tested separately directly on the DB.

anyone has an idea what could it be?

Comment: I understand somehow what you want to achieve, but can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Are you telling, that without DB test works as expected (returns 200)?

Comment: If the test works with fake JDBC code and sends a 404 with the real one, then the JDBC code has a problem, or the required data is not there. Whatever the reason, the createObjectSuccessResponse() method must create a 404 response instead of a success response as its name indicates. Use your debugger and step through the code step by step to see what is happening on the server.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought about the same, but if there is an exception, then a.) it should be clear from log b.) 500 should be returned, or not?

Comment: My guess is that there is no exception. There is just some special response (null? empty string? "error"?) returned by getAdServerComparison(), and when that special response is passed to createObjectSuccessResponse(), it creates a 404 instead of a 200.

Comment: That, or an exception is thrown, and this exception is annotated to be translated to a 404 error. Or there is an error handler returning a 404 when the exception is thrown. Anyway, debugging would tell.

Comment: thanks for the comments and sorry for the late response (time difference...). I figured what was the problem based on JB's comment. I didn't mock the repository and after further investigation I found out that when I ran on Junit there was no db to work against and that was the problem. I will edit the original question with the solution.

Comment: Where are the classes `AbstractControllerIntegrationTest` and `Resource` from?

Comment: they are part of the infrastructure of the project I added code to

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the test using Junit the Spring boot didn't actually built the DB connection (or something of that sort). What I did is to mock the service I'm calling using Mockito:

```
Mockito.when(adServersReportsService.getAdServerComparison(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn("test");
```